# Maximum difference of sum of odd and even index elements of a subarray

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, sub-array

Given an array of N integers (can be positive/negative), calculate the maximum **difference** of the sum of odd and even indexed elements of any **subarray**, assuming the array follows **0 based** indexing.

For Example:

A = [ 1, 2, -1, 4, -1, -5 ]

Optimally selected subarray should be : [ 2, -1, 4, -1 ]

```
   sum of even indexed elements (0 based) : 2 + 4 = 6

   sum of odd indexed elements (0 based)  : (-1) + (-1) = -2

                        Total Difference  : 6 - (-2) = 6 + 2 = 8
```

Comment: What TC are you aiming for? What is the TC of your current solution? Or rather, do you any solution or attempts at it? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you negate all the odd indexed elements, then this problem becomes one of finding the maximum (or minimum) subarray sum.

[Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) gives an O(n) method of solving such a problem.

For the given example:

```
# Original array
A = [1,2,-1,4,-1,-5]
# negate alternate elements
B = [-1,2,1,4,1,-5]
# maximum subarray
max_value = 2+1+4+1 = 8
# minimum subarray
min_value = -5
# biggest difference in subarray
max(max_value,-min_value) = max(8,--5) = max(8,5) = 8
```

Comment: You would want to take the maximum of (value of maximum subarray) and -(value of minimum subarray) to find the maximum difference

Comment: Added an example